# Why does __LINE__ not work with this consteval function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr, consteval

I wrote a small function to convert the `__LINE__` macro into an array of `wchar_t` so that the line can be represented as a string at compile time (no null terminating character).

```
template <int Line>
consteval auto line_number()
{
    auto get_num_digits{ [](int num) consteval {
        auto count{1};
        while (num /= 10) ++count;
        return count;
    } };
    constexpr auto num_digits{ get_num_digits(Line) };
    std::array<wchar_t, num_digits> digits;

    auto line{ Line };
    for (auto i{ num_digits - 1 }; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        digits[i] = L'0' + (line % 10);
        line /= 10;
    }

    return digits;
}
```

When I call it via `line_number<123>()` it works fine, but when calling it as `line_number<__LINE__>()` the compiler (MSVC 2022 C++20) complains that `__LINE__` isn't a constant expression, even though it is a pre-defined macro. Is there any way to get it to accept `__LINE__` as constant? I also tried doing things like `__LINE__ + 0` or `__LINE__ + 4 - (2 * 2)` in hopes that the compiler takes the `__LINE__` and does some math on it and somehow makes it a constant but that does not seem to work either.

It is also strange because IntelliSense detects `__LINE__` as a constant, as in, the function call can be evaluated with the right return value, but the compiler does not.

Comment: Did you set the compiler to C++20 mode?  It [compiles without error here](https://godbolt.org/z/encxG4eWj).  By default, the compiler used by VIsual Studio is C++14.

Comment: Yes it is C++ 20 @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Well, the link shows that msvc 19.0 compiles the code with no errors.

Comment: There was a comment here a second ago with a workaround, let my try it. Even in that link it worked on compiler explorer

Comment: Okay, that works fine. It seems like compiler explorer doesn't have this problem because it is not using edit and continue in its compile flags.

Comment: @ArushAgarampur Bizarre, I'd consider a bug report.

Comment: @john -- Yes I agree, a bug report should be filed.   Microsoft should give a better error message that macros such as `__LINE__` , `__FILE__` and probably others will make constant evaluation produce compiler errors on the `Edit and Continue` setting.  It shouldn't take digging into StackOverflow to know about this.